# oracle apex: display an image based on url as a report column

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

On my classic report I have a column that stored a URL to an image. Is it possible to have an image loaded on a classic report? Or is there another way to display an image as a column in the report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply HTML tags to the URL.

For example, if this is your table:

```
create table images 
  (id     number,
   url    varchar2(100));

insert into images (id, url) values (1, 'http://www.my_site.com/my_car.jpg');
```

then the Apex classic report's query should look like this:

```
select 
  id,
  '<img src=' || URL || '>' url
from images
```

Navigate to URL column's properties and set "Escape special characters" to NO (because you want Apex to properly interpret the IMG tags).

Run the report and you should see all the images.

Comment: If I may add to the above answer, you can use the height and width properties with in that <img> tag to control the size of the images.

In addition, make sure to have the column type as 'Standard Report Column' if you are in component view or Plain text (Designer View).

Comment: All right with the answer above. I have preferred to use the "HTML Expression" field in the report column settings, my select gets cleaner. In that field you would put something like <img src="#COLUMN_NAME#" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">.

Answer (score 0):

Select the particular Column under columns. 
In the column attrbutes, Under Link Select Target as "URL" and provide the column name format as &.